# Creating a Debian Package from CMake Project

Tags: cmake, debian, deb

I am considering to create a Debian package from an existing library (paho-mqtt-c). The project uses CMake as its build system. After some research I think I need to create two or three different packages:

- libpaho-mqtt3 (with library .so files and related stuff)
- libpaho-mqtt3-dev (with header files)
- also maybe I need a third package with sample files or documentation (called `paho-mqtt3`?)

I have done some research and it seems there exist at least three different ways how I can create a Debian package when I use CMake as my build system:

1. Use debmake procedure described in Debian documentation ([Chapter 8](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch08.en.html#cmake-multi)).
2. Use [cmake-debhelper](https://github.com/sebknzl/cmake-debhelper).
3. Use [dh-cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/debian/dh-cmake)

I have looked into all three methods and it seems each has some advantages and disadvantages.

## Debmake

As far as I have understood using debmake assumes I have an upstream tarball with the sources and the build system and then I invoke debmake on the extracted tarball. Afterwards I get a lot of templates which I need to manually adjust to fill in the missing gaps. I started doing this but it seems quite complex.

## cmake-debhelper

I tried to use it but received lots of errors. The github page has an [open issue](https://github.com/sebknzl/cmake-debhelper/issues/3) with no solution so I stopped looking at this. This is also what the `paho-mqtt-c` build system is currently using, but it does not work due to the issue linked.

## dh-cmake

I briefly looked into this and it seems to be the most modern solution and it should be possible to combine this with CPack. However, it seems dh-cmake is only available for Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04, but I am using Ubuntu 19.10 so I was not able to install dh-cmake on my system.

Have I missed anything in my research? What are the recommended steps to create a Debian package from a software managed with CMake and which documentation is useful to read?

Comment: You tried with CPack?[cpack example](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/examples/linux/DEB)

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012811/how-to-build-a-deb-file-for-cmake-from-source

Answer (score 1):

In short, on Ubuntu you need to create at least these files:

```
debian/
 changelog
 control
 copyright
 rules
```

And then run `debuild` and it will run `cmake install` to temporary folder and pack an installable `deb` package from it.
To quickly create those `debian` files run `dh_make --createorig` and press `s` for source package.
Then you'll need to carefully edit debian files as described in [Chapter 4. Required files under the debian directory](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html)
 of Debian New Maintainers' Guide.

If you need to set cmake properties or make any other configuration then you'll need to adjust `override_dh_auto_configure` in `rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
export DH_VERBOSE = 1

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- \
    -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) \
    -DIWINFO_SUPPORT=OFF
```

Here the `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)` and `-DIWINFO_SUPPORT=OFF` will be directly passed to cmake.

You can then upload your package to Ubuntu PPA:

```
debuild -S -I
dput dput ppa:your-launchpad-user/your-ppa ../*_source.changes
```

After that PPA build bot will compile and publish your package to PPA and you'll see them on [https://launchpad.net/~your-launchpad-user/+archive/ubuntu/your-ppa/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyour-launchpad-user/+archive/ubuntu/your-ppa/+packages)

Unfortunately there is a lot of other steps, I just described briefly.

The dh-cmake is needed for more sophisticated things. CPack won't work for you if you want to publish to PPA because its buildbot will anyway run debhelper (short version of debuild) so it needs for the `debian` folder

Comment: Thanks for this answer. From what I have gathered so far, I thought that `dh_make` (with an underscore) is an older solution and the more modern approach is to use `debmake` to generate the Debian files, not sure if thats right. Anyway, I was not aware of the `--createorig` option of `dh_make`, that is certainly useful, this way I would not need a `source tarball` to start off with. If your sources are in git, then your folder is probably not in the `package-version` format, so I would either need to rename the folder or use the `-p <package>_<version>` option.

Answer (score 1):

or you could use `cpack` with `cmake` to generate a `deb` fairly easy to do but **cmake** and **cpack** are poorly documented still they work well
I suggest adding the following to the bottom of CMakeLists.txt

```
# generate postinst file in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} from template                        #
CONFIGURE_FILE("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/postinst.in" "postinst" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)


    # generate a DEB when cpack is run
    SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
    SET(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR TRUE)
    SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "grizzlysmit@smit.id.au")
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "0")
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "1")
    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/CPack.Description.txt")
    SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_README "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/README.md")
    SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/LICENCE")
    SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libreadline8, libreadline-dev")
    SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "Grizzly")
    # make postinst run after install                                                #
    SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/postinst;")
    
    
    include(CPack)
```

the `postisnt`  is to run a script after the install see [CMAKE/CPACK:I want to the deb executes a bash script after installed, but it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869601/cmake-cpacki-want-to-the-deb-executes-a-bash-script-after-installed-but-it-doe/74947521#74947521) for more on that.